# Can someone give me some examples of partial differentials that are not also exact differentials?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A classic example might be the vector Field = <-y,x> where the curl is non zero and the potential function is not path independent and is therefore NOT an exact differential. Even though < -y,x>  does not have a potential function can it be the case that it still has  a partial derivative of some function even though the function is not a potential function? Ultimately I am trying to see if in fact every exact differential is also a partial differential with some added property whose outcome will always insure a 0 curl. Although this question is very close to another one it has a different approach that will hopefully better visualize the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition of a potential function $f$ for a force field $\mathbf F$ is that $\mathbf F = \pm\nabla f$. If you're in what's called a simply connected region (no "holes" of dimension two less), then $\text{curl}(\mathbf F) = \mathbf 0$ if and only if there is a potential function $f$ for $\mathbf F$. (I'm assuming $\mathbf F$ has continuous partial derivatives everywhere on its simply connected domain.)

By the way, in your example, $\mathbf F=(-y,x)$ has *no* potential function. Aside from the curl test, you can easily try to find a potential function by integrating and you arrive at a contradiction. So it makes no sense to say "the potential function is not path independent"; what you mean is that the work done by the force field (or line integrals) is not path independent.

The standard counterexample when simple connectivity fails is the force field
$$\mathbf F = \left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right).$$
It does nonzero work around any closed curve winding around the origin, so it cannot be conservative, and yet $\text{curl}(\mathbf F) = \mathbf 0$. This does not contradict what I said earlier because the domain of $\mathbf F$ is the plane missing the origin, and this is not simply connected.

Comment: Note that the basis for all of this is two relatively intuitive facts: 1. the line integral of any "reasonable" function on a degenerate path consisting of a single point is zero 2. line integrals of curl-free fields are invariant under a homotopy of their path (this last result doesn't need the field to be conservative, though).

Comment: Indeed, I should add that in...

Comment: Here if we take $M$ and $N$ as component function of $F$ then $M_y =N_x$ On $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. So Mdx+Ndy is exact and by necessary and sufficient condition we have potential function on  $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}.$ which is not the case . So does it mean that while proving sufficient part of exact ness we need domain D simply connected?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $Mdx+Ndy$ is only *locally* exact, necessarily globally exact only when the domain is simply connected.